# Keep the ImageView's Final View while scrolling

Tags: java, android, caching, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal-Image-Loader to handle the display of my images, I am using a gridview like implementation in showing the images. Before the images are shown it will be downloaded first and cached into the sd card. While the images are still being downloaded, I handled the view with lazy list implementation for each images.

*Problem:*

After all the images are downloaded and ready for showing and 
every time I scroll the gridview, up and down direction the images are somewhat being downloaded again with lazy list,
I believe it is being downloaded from the cache folder(sd card) of my application. Is there any way that I can keep the images(final state) while I am scrolling? Such that I don't need to downloaded it everytime I scroll to attain smooth scrolling.? I need to wait until the image is fully loaded from the sd card so that I can have smooth scrolling.

**I got this setting from UIL, but I don't see any effect on this.**

```
.resetViewBeforeLoading(false|true)
```

---

*edit*

I also tried this,

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
```

---

*same as below*

```
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Turn off stale checking. Our connections break all the time anyway,
        // and it's not worth it to pay the penalty of checking every time.
        HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
        // Default connection and socket timeout of 10 seconds. Tweak to taste.
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config =
                new ImageLoaderConfiguration
                        .Builder(getActivity())
                        .threadPoolSize(3)
                        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                        .imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(getActivity(), new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params)))
                        .build();
        imageLoader.init(config);
```

---

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(icon)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
```

I tried experimenting, on the settings still the same.

Comment: Can you post your full code of UIL configuration?

Comment: try to see the update sir.

Comment: Use androidquery framework its amazing and it takes care of cache management and load images asynchronously. Find here http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: @BirajZalavadia not sure if this can resolve my problem in keeping the image while scolling, androidquery I am used to have the UIL.

Comment: If I understand right the problem is in recreating elements of the gridView (`GridView` like `ListView` doesn't contain all elements, but create them when they become visible). You can write your adapter which would keep all elements and returnan existing one instead of creating it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is, you need to cache images in some directory like our application cache. Where images resides instead of memory cache. Using File caching will not increase Heap size and images will fetch from directory immediately after download.

```
File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "directory_name");
if (!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdir();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            YourActivity.this).threadPoolSize(5)
            .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 3)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            // .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2000000)) // You
            // can pass your own memory cache implementation
            .memoryCacheSize(1048576 * 10)
            // 1MB=1048576 *declare 20 or more size if images are more than
            // 200
            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
            // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
            // .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
            .build();

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
imageLoader.clearDiscCache();

options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.avatar)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.home_shortcut).cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().build();
```

Note: I have used old version of UIL.

**Purpose**

```
imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
```

This will clear memory when you run this code again. This is useful when your URL is same but image is different.

```
imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
```

This will clear disk before starting downloading to directory. This is useful when your directory has old images.

**Memory Cache vs Disk Cache**

Heap means your application memory allocation. If you don't provide disk cache, suppose your images have fix sizes of 100KB, 10 images has size of 1 MB will be stored in Memory instead of disk. While disk is not memory. It is a directory, physically on internal disk, has its own space inside. So instead of providing memory caching, disk cache is good as per memory utilization. Yes it is true that it is little bit slow but this will never effect your performance.

Comment: I tried comparing the performance, and it did go well. But not sure what this means `"not increase Heap size and images will fetch from directory immediately after download"`, what did the system did on the first config? Also, I am not sure what is the purpose of this codes, `.clearMemoryCache()`, `.clearDiscCache()`. Also, I tried to locate the cache dir, but nothing there.

Comment: `data/yourapp/cache/missing folder_directory_name`

Comment: Directory will be created as per my code. I have tried in one of my project and is running very well.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for extending your help! I only learned it from you.!

Comment: sir  Chintan, what I did is to change it to `getExternalCacheDir()` instead of `getCacheDir()`. Now I can see it externally.